# Finding polynomial degree $1$ of $f(x)=\text{erf}(x-1)$ at $x=1$

Tags: calculus, integration, polynomials, spline, error-function

**Question:** Find the polynomial of degree $1$ that has the highest possible order of contact with $f(x)=\text{erf}(x-1)$ at $x=1$. Plot the spline knotted at $(1,0)$ with $f(x)$ on the right and your polynomial on the left for $0 \leq x \leq 2$.

I think $$f(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\left(\left(\int_{0}^{x} e^{-t^2} dt\right) - \left(\int_{0}^{1} e^{-t^2} dt\right)\right).$$
When I go to calculate $g(x)$, I get $$\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{1} e^{-t^2} dt\cdot x.$$ However, when I graph this spline it doesn't look correct. Are there any tips on how to find $g(x)$?
I used $g(x) = a_0x^0 + a_1x^1$ with $a_0=0$ and $$a_1= \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{1} e^{-t^2} dt.$$

Comment: This looks awful. [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: That's unreadable.

Comment: @Shaun Sorry thank you, obviously new here lol

Comment: It is not true that $\text{erf}(x-1) =\text{erf} (x) -\text{erf}(1) $. Shouldn't  $a_1 = f'(1)$ by the Taylor formula?

Comment: @Gary Would the erf(x-1)= $-\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \left(\int_0^{1-x} e^{-t^2} dt\right)$ ? and you're right about $a_1$ I completely forgot about that

Comment: Why not just $$\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{x-1} \mathrm{e}^{-t^2} \mathrm{d}t\;?$$